# dropzone.js and autoProcessQueue=false , events not working

Tags: events, file-upload, dropzone.js

I use `dropzone.js` not directly on form but on DIV, so i init it programmatically and `autoProcessQueu=false.`

*with this configuration when i put a file, or dragged it all events are not fired.*

i want add file, then make a `js` function, and process file on URL only on a button submit.

any idea ?

```
Dropzone.options.myDropZone = {
            autoProcessQueue: false,
            uploadMultiple: false,

            url: "/file/post",

            init: function () {
                this.on("dragend", function (event) {
                    alert (event); //all in this event not fired
                      $('#myDropZone').hide();
                    $('#formUpload').show();
                });

            }
    };
```

html

```
 <div class=col-md-6>
    <div class="dropzone bordered" id="myDropZone">
        <div class="dz-default dz-message">
          <div class="icon"><span class="s7-cloud-upload"></span></div>
          <h2>Drag and Drop files here</h2>
          <input type="file" id="video"/>
        </div>
    </div>  
        <div id="formUpload" class="bordered" style="display:none;">
            @_videoUploadForm(videoUploadForm)
        </div>
 </div>
```

when i comment `autoProcessQueue` it it fired but file are processed.

i only want send form (file and input) in same time in only one form